# How to load Html in Browser field for Blackberry Os version 4.6.1.310 i

Tags: blackberry, java-me

```
public BrowserFieldDemoScreen()
 {
        BrowserField mybroBrowserField=new BrowserField();
        add(mybroBrowserField);
        mybroBrowserField.displayContent("
           <html><body><h1>hello world! This blackbery apps
           </h1></body></html>", "http://localhost");
 }
```

I'm new in Blackberry application development, I have load html in browser and I have write code for that it works perfectly for more than OS version 5.

But I have create app for 4.6.1.310 model number 8900 not working giveing some uncaught Exception. Please tell me what I have to change so that it should work on 4.6.1.310 version also,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use BrowserField class below Blackberry OS 5.0

Before running application go through sdk docs.

Answer (score 0):

The BlackBerry Facebook SDK was written to use embedded browser functionality, before (5.0) `BrowserField` was available.  I believe that code is free to use and modify to your needs.

[see the project here](http://www.baskoro.org/facebook-blackberry-sdk/archive/sample-codes)

Look in the sample code (scroll down the page) at his `LoginScreen` class.

You should be able to modify that class to serve your purposes.  This particular class, of course, has a hardcoded URL that points to Facebook.  You will obviously change that to accept whatever URLs you like, and remove other references to `facebook` classes you don't need.  You will definitely need more than just the `LoginScreen` class, but all its dependencies should be available on that site.

Post a comment if there's any problems getting this to work.  I have some other legacy code that does this successfully, but I'm not free to post it ... but quickly looking at the Baskoro code I linked to appears like it does basically the same thing.